# SSRS - producing csv file with mixed format header & footer

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a query,

I have 3 CTE's produced by a TSQL query, which are used as a list of union-ed demographics, we have a requirement to submit this file in a particular format with a header and footer row in each file saved as csv. Can someone suggest the best method to produce the following format from SSRS, ultimately the header and footer will be generated from a SQL table which will hold the available submission ID's, I am wondering if this format can be automated from SSRS, or if there is a better approach, as you can see the header and footer appear to be tab separated, without the additional columns, then the comma separated data block, followed by another tab separated footer.

Any suggestions would be appreciated - thanks very much

format required below (dummy data):

```
 0001011RNL DBS 473520180116
 10,6374635,19540714,,,7253647987,p1,,john,,2,3 MADE UP ST,,local,CUMBRIA,,ca12 0T1,,,,,,,,A82635,,
 10,9283746,19650325,,,7536482965,p2,,peter,,2,38 MADE UP ST,,WIGTON,,,ca12 0T3,,,,,,,,A82045,,
 9901011RNL DBS 473520180116
```

UPDATED based on user suggestions: SSIS appears to be the best approach - I have found the following resource which appears to be what is required, I have taken this from https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic815666-148-1.aspx

provided by John Dempsey

1. Place 2 Data Flow Tasks on the Control Flow tab.
2. Use the first Data Flow Task to generate your Header and Detail records (rows)
   a. Obtain the data from your data source
   b. Transform your data as needed to satisfy the results for your Detail Rows
   c. Set up your Flat File Destination in the layout for your Detail Rows. (Don't worry about Header yet)
   d. Upon opening your Flat File Destination task you will notice a item for the "Header:". If you were to enter something in the box here it would be hard-coded as the header for you within your file. But, instead of it being hard-coded you can make it dynamic. You can create a SSIS variable to store your dynamically built header information, then assign it to the Header property of the Flat File Destination in the 1st Data Flow task.
3. Set dynamic Header SSIS variable to Header property of Flat File Destination in 1st Data Flow Task.
   a. On the Control Flow Tab select the first Data Flow Task then go to the properties window for task
   b. Expand [+] Expressions property and click the [...] button
   c. In the Property Expressions Editor window click in the left column to bring up a list of properties available within the Data Flow Task for you Header and Detail Rows.
   d. Choose the property [Flat File Destination].[Header] (if you haven't renamed it yet) setting the expression to the name of your SSIS variable name you created for your dynamic header.
4. Your dynamic header should now show up when you run the first data flow task with your detail rows.
5. Open up the second data flow and create a source for your footer, I used a script component as an input data source, mapping the source row to an SSIS variable that contained my Footer Row.
6. Create your Flat File Destination for you footer making sure that you set the Overwrite property = False. Your Flat File Destination will be the same file name as your header and detail file name from you first Data Flow Task, but the layout will be different in order to line up with the footer.
7. Upon running you SSIS, the package will run through executing your first Data Flow Task which writes the data from the Header property, then each detail row. Then, it will run the second Data Flow Task writing the footer row to the end of the same file used in your Header and Detail Data Flow Task.

Comment: I would recommend using an Integration Services project for this.

Comment: Thanks Tony, I had thought this may be a useful approach, can you suggest which elements would work for me, I'll then research how to hang it all together

Comment: You can use a "Execute SQL Task" control for the CTE and then a “Flat File Destination” control to create the csc file.

Comment: That's supposed to read "CSV file". I was on my phone.