How to insert "meta data" in beginning and end of SQL Query
I'm writing a small SQL query for work to automate some jobs that we regularly do. I have managed to figure out most of it but one thing is bugging me.
I have to generate a CSV file that contains a the output from our ERP system and at the beginning and end of the query I have to have a start text and an EOF. I have somewhat solved this by making the query and then using Union all to insert the start and EOF in the file. The problem is however that the start and EOF line has the wrong format.
But let me start by attaching a sample that show the principle of the query
Select
'Meta Data:12 seperator:; Endtag EOF' as 'USER'
,'' as 'ID'
,'' as 'Date'

union all

Select top 3
bruger as 'USER'
,id as 'ID'
,dato as 'DATE'

 from dbo.TableName

 union all

 Select
'EOF' as 'USER'
,'' as 'ID'
,'' as 'Date'

The Results from this looks like this when I save it as a CSV
”Meta Data:12 seperator:; Endtag EOF”;;2024-05-01
User1;123;2024-05-01
User2;456;2024-05-01
User3;789;2024-05-01
EOF;;2024-05-01

However I want the result to be like this
Meta Data:12 seperator:; Endtag EOF
User1;123;2024-05-01
User2;456;2024-05-01
User3;789;2024-05-01
EOF

I hope you have some good suggestions for me.

Not sure this is a true duplicate but there are a lot of similar questions re; https://stackoverflow.com/q/3169220/125981 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/63763209/125981 and as THIS one indicates this is quite commonly a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/6776883/125981

Search for more https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+generate+csv+from+query One of the 190 (as of today) should help you out

In SQL Server there is no straight forward solution for this. One way I described in my answer, there is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48297248/ssrs-producing-csv-file-with-mixed-format-header-footer

Last time I remember having to do it (~10 years ago) I had to manually combine columns into one string. e.g.
-- Header
SELECT 'Meta Data:12 seperator:; Endtag EOF' as Col
UNION ALL
-- Data
SELECT CONCAT_WS( ';', bruger, id, dato ) AS Col from dbo.TableName
UNION ALL
-- Footer
SELECT 'EOF' AS Col


Thank you for the suggestion, i have successfully tested it  on my sample database and it seems to work even when i add  an extra union all and where statements. I will now try and combine the entire SQL script for our EOP system.
BTW. there is a small typing error in the suggested SQL. You write CONCAST_WS and i corrected it to CONCAT_WS

RE "You write CONCAST_WS and i corrected it to CONCAT_WS " - apologies for this and thanks to @siggemannen for fixing the typo in my answer. Feel to mark the answer as accepted when you finish your testing.
